# ng-repeat directive doesn't work on <tr> / table row element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use the ng-repeat directive to create table rows with a list of campaign names.
However, I am not able to get any results, though I am still able to see one of the children of the array displaying correctly.
Here is my view code:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{$ctrl.contact.Campaigns[0].CampaignName}}</p>
        <tr ng-repeat="campaign in $ctrl.contact.Campaigns">
            <label>
                {{campaign.CampaignName}}
            </label>
         </tr>
    </div>
```

I can successfully see the paragraph element above and it shows the expected data, but not the table row elements.

I don't see any errors in the browser console.

How can I make the ng-repeat directive work in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `<tr>` / table row element didn't have a parent `<table>` element containing it.
This is solved by simply adding in table tags around the orphaned `<tr>` element:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="campaign in $ctrl.contact.Campaigns">
                    <label>
                        {{campaign.CampaignName}}
                    </label>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```